# How to obtain a reference to the Embedded Jetty request scope

Tags: embedded-jetty

I'm using the Errai Framework on an embedded Jetty setup and running a Weld-SE environment.

The Errai framework uses PicketLink for security, which in turn scopes some key beans in the @RequestScoped. As a result, I am encountering "No active contexts for scope errors" when making calls to the security API.

My questions is how can I tap into the Jetty and/or Errai APIs to manually initialize the RequestScope on the right thread for my environment ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this it is possible to start the @RequestScope inside a Filter :

```
public class WeldRequestScopeFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(
            WeldRequestScopeFilter.class.getSimpleName());

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        logger.trace("Filter destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        final String url = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL()
                .toString();
        final Map<String, Object> requestDataStore = new HashMap<>(10);

        final WeldContainer WELD = WeldContainer
                .instance(Application.WELD_CONTAINER_ID);
        final BoundRequestContext requestContext = WELD
                .select(BoundRequestContext.class).get();

        logger.info("Activating @RequestScoped for request on {}", url);
        requestContext.associate(requestDataStore);
        requestContext.activate();

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        logger.info("Deactivating @RequestScoped for request on {}", url);
        requestContext.invalidate();
        requestContext.deactivate();
        requestContext.dissociate(requestDataStore);

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        logger.trace("Filter initialized");
    }

}
```